# What is the difference between Graphical Shell and Desktop Environment?

Tags: desktop-environment, terminology

What is the exact difference between Graphical Shell and Desktop Environment?

Comment: Please edit your question and elaborate how you define a "graphical shell".

Comment: The difference is whatever the person using those two terms wants it to be. You have to ask them, not us.

Comment: Why is my comment deleted???

Comment: @Noob_Guy Because it was flagged by one or several users as "unfriendly or unkind".

Comment: Regarding the comment from @Panki, do you mean "terminal" (an application running in a GUI displaying a shell) and/or "console" (a terminal interface with a shell presented without any graphical user interface attached) when you use the word "shell"? Note too that there is something called "Gnome Shell", which is not in fact a command line environment, but a graphical desktop environment.  This is why they wanted you to be a bit more specific with the use of terms.

Comment: This appears to have already been answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8676751.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment), emphasis mine:

> [...] a **desktop environment (DE)** is an implementation of the desktop metaphor made of a bundle of programs running on top of a computer operating system that share a common graphical user interface (GUI), sometimes described as a **graphical shell**

They are more or less synonyms, although the term Desktop Environment is more precise and should be preferred.

Examples of DEs in Linux are KDE, CDE, and GNOME.

Answer (score -2):

If you define GUI Shell as single process like CLI Shell, then I can tell you Desktop Environment contains much more things like File Manager, Music/Video Player, Configuration Tools, Input Method, etc. Bascially, Desktop Environment is a bunch of application that gives end-users ready-to-use experience.